# Start multiple instances of consumers on starting RabbitMQ server

Tags: php, rabbitmq, message-queue

I want to start multiple instances of consumers as soon as the RabbitMQ server is started. The number of instances should be configurable i.e. store the number of instances in a file and as the RabbitMQ server starts, the instances should start.

I believe there needs to be written some line in /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server file in

```
start_rabbitmq()
```

function. This function will call my cron which has the consumer code and inside the cron file it reads a file which has a constant specifying the number of instances to run.

Am I going right and what should be written to automatically run instances?